# fonts not showing in firefox createjs

Tags: createjs

Fonts are missing in firefox
I'm exporting from Flash

this is what I'm using, have tried different fonts I really need to  have dynamic text.

```
    this.text = new cjs.Text("Find out more", "12px helvetica", "#FFFFFF");
```

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

got this working, I was importing css incorectly